# Odd .Net serialization problem

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I had an odd problem today when I was trying to serialize an object.  The object was generated via "Add service reference" from a web service (svcutil.exe).

The problem was that the below property (agencyId) was not being serialized with the rest of the object.  Out of desperation I commented the property below it because it had the "XMLIgnoreAttribute" assigned... after I commented the ignored property, the agencyId field serialized as expected.

Can someone please explain to me why this behavior occurred?
Thanks!!

```
        /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
    public string agencyId
    {
        get {
            return this.agencyIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.agencyIdField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("agencyId");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool agencyIdSpecified
    {
        get
        {
            return this.agencyIdFieldSpecified;
        }
        set
        {
            this.agencyIdFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("agencyIdSpecified");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the error message you were getting as well? Also, the exceptions thrown by .NET for sterilization errors are sometimes misleading as the actual error might be buried in a couple of inner exceptions.

Comment: heh :) sterilization errors... classic typo :D 'unable to sterilize this object, breeding could occur'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a pattern (for XmlSerializer), that a property Foo will also look for either "bool FooSpecified", or "bool ShouldSerializeFoo()" - and if found, only serialize Foo if this other member returns true. So I assume that agencyIdSpecified had never been set to true? Removing this member would make it always serialize (unless you add a `[DefaultValue]` or similar).

This type of behaviour is used to model optional values on the occasion that we really need to know whether it was in the original data - i.e. does it have the value 0 because the caller told us that number, or because that is simply the default.

Note that the "FooSpecified" member commonly has `[XmlIgnore]` so that XmlSerializer knows that it shouldn't be considered as data for serialization. This isn't necessary (or legal, in fact) with "ShouldSerializeFoo()", since methods are never serialized.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of XmlIgnoreAttribute is to tell the XmlSerializer that you don't want to serialize that property: it's the whole point.  So what you're seeing is the designed behavior of that code.  A much better question would be why the class implementor chose to decorate that property in that way.

Comment: I think the oddity is that the agenecyId was being ignored when the XmlIgnore attribute is on the agencyIdSpecified field.